# How do I optimise my website for "mobile view optimisation'

Tags: optimization, mobile, wordpress-theming

We have a website YogiPi.com where we duplicated the homepage and changed it as we wanted.

When we view it on our laptop and tablet the copied page is working but in the mobile view we cannot see the last part of the page?..

We have not changed any settings and would be very grateful for any help to resolved this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Its all about the css. You should check all what is missing for mobile view.

Comment: Thank you Prakash Ji , how do I check the css ?...sorry for not knowing ☺️